# Bamboo Rest API multiple expands

Tags: api, bamboo

Tried to fetch information for multiple builds from bamboo using the rest api. The information for the builds should include the ticket names the builds affacted and the commit messages for the commits which are included in these builds.

My Approch was the following:

```
{bambooUrl}/rest/api/latest/result/{projectkey}-{buildKey}.json?expand=results.result.vcsRevisions
{bambooUrl}/rest/api/latest/result/{projectkey}-{buildKey}.json?expand=results.result.jiraIssues
```

Both of these calls work fine but I need them merged together in one call:
I have tried the following:

```
{bambooUrl}/rest/api/latest/result/{projectkey}-{buildKey}.json?expand=results.result.jiraIssues,results.result.vcsRevisions
```

But this call just expands the vcsRevisions for me. Does someone have an tip for me how to use multiple expands?

Answer (score 1):

I might be too late to answer your question, but solution might help others.

{bambooUrl}/rest/api/latest/result/{projectkey}-{buildKey}.json?expand=jiraIssues,vcsRevisions
worked for me

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Had to search everywhere for this. Thanks!